# SQL View from 2 table with Like Constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

I would like to create a view in SQL from 2 tables with:

Table A:

[image]

Table B:

[image]

I would like my view sort :

```
ID  ALIAS   Zone
1   Alias_1 Zone_1
2   Alias_1 Zone_1
3   Alias_2 Zone_2
4   Alias_2 Zone_2
5   Alias_3 No Zone
6   Alias_3 No Zone
```

IF table.b.column CONTAINS table.a.NAME_1 AND table.a.NAME_2
And if not contains view.zone = No Zone

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please edit your question to include the tables in the question text.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please don't include links to outside websites in your questions. If someone else is having a similar problem in the future this will make the question/answers useless to them if those become dead links. Instead, include everything needed in your question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What are the relations between the tables?

Comment: Don't store data is you do in table b ,with blank separated items! It will only cause you lots of trouble. One value/row is the SQL way!

Answer (score 0):

Storing data as you have with a column containing multiple pieces of data (i.e., your member column in table B) is a big mistake in database design. If possible, you should redesign to avoid that.

That said, there may be times when you inherit data and have no choice for the time being. In that case, this should get you pretty close:

```
SELECT
    A.alias,
    COALESCE(B.z_name, 'No Zone') AS zone
FROM
    A
LEFT OUTER JOIN B ON
    B.member LIKE '%' + A.name_1 + '%' AND
    B.member LIKE '%' + A.name_2 + '%'
```

This will still run into problems if a zone name might include another zone name, for example zones of "abc" and "abcd". If you can guarantee that the zone names are all space delimited then it becomes possible to handle, but is still tricky.

Also, you weren't clear on what the "id" is in the result set. It's obviously not from table "A". If it's just supposed to be an incrementing number then you can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` function, although I don't know what use that has in a view.

Comment: You can add spaces before and after the names. E.g. `' ' + B.member + ' ' LIKE '% ' + A.name_1 + ' %'`.

Comment: If the member column follows that rule - as I said.

Comment: `' ' + aaa bbb ccc' + ' '` => `' aaa bbb ccc '`. `'% ' + 'aaa' + ' %'` => `'% aaa %'`. I.e. `' aaa bbb ccc ' LIKE '% aaa %'`.

Comment: Didn't see the spaces around the B.member column, yes your expression would work.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no relation between these table then can use [`CHARINDEX`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx)

Sorry,fiddle Not Working.

**Query:**

```
select A.ALIAS,
ISNULL(
  (select top 1 B.Z_Name From zone B where 
 CHARINDEX(A.NAME1,B.Member)>0 
 And CHARINDEX(A.NAME2,B.Member)>0)
  ,'NO ZONE') as ZoneName
FROM member A
```

**Tabel:**

```
create table member
(
  ID int identity(1,1),
  ALIAS nvarchar(50),
  NAME1 nvarchar(50),
  NAME2 nvarchar(50)
)
insert into member(ALIAS,NAME1,NAME2)
values
('Alias_1','aaa','bbb'),
('Alias_1','aaa','ccc'),
('Alias_2','ddd','eee'),
('Alias_2','ddd','ffff'),
('Alias_3','ggg','hhh'),
('Alias_3','ggg','iii')

create table zone
(
  ID int identity(1,1),
  Z_Name nvarchar(50),
  Member nvarchar(50)
)
insert into zone(Z_Name,Member)
values
('Zone_1','aaa bbb ccc'),
('Zone_2','ddd eee ffff')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make this more 3rd normal form. You should go through this exercise to fix this data anyway. So first you need a function that splits a string like your Members strings into a table.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnSplitString] 
( 
    @string NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    @delimiter CHAR(1) 
) 
RETURNS @output TABLE(splitdata NVARCHAR(MAX) 
) 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @start INT, @end INT 
    SELECT @start = 1, @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string) 
    WHILE @start < LEN(@string) + 1 BEGIN 
        IF @end = 0  
            SET @end = LEN(@string) + 1

        INSERT INTO @output (splitdata)  
        VALUES(SUBSTRING(@string, @start, @end - @start)) 
        SET @start = @end + 1 
        SET @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string, @start)

    END 

    RETURN 
END

GO
```

Now you use this to fix your data:

```
declare @id int = 0
declare @index int = 0
declare @MembersString varchar(max) 

declare @test table 
(id int, 
Z_Name varchar(50), 
Member varchar(8000))

declare @fixed table 
(id  int identity,
ZoneId int , 
SingleMember varchar(256))

insert into @test
values(1, 'Zone_1', 'aaa bbb ccc'),
(2, 'Zone_2', 'ddd eee fff')


while 1=1 
begin

    select @id = min(id)
    from @test t
    where id > @id

    if(@id is null)
        break

    select @MembersString = t.member
    from @test t
    where id = @id

    insert into @fixed
    (ZoneId, SingleMember)
    select @id, m.splitdata 
    from dbo.fnSplitString(@MembersString, ' ') m

end

select *
from @fixed f
```

The results:
[image]

From here it is easy to get the output you want.